# Using DTM and STR files from Surpac in ArcGIS Desktop for slope stability analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, slope, surpac

I currently have 1m and 5m topography files from Surpac in the format of both DTM and STR and I am tasked to perform a slope stability analysis of the area. I do not have any knowledge to operate Surpac and I only have basic understanding in using both AutoCAD and ArcGIS (ArcMap 10.2).

I have perform some basic slope stability analysis using ArcGIS Slope (Spatial Analysis) before, but the files are in DEM files.

I have Googled around for a while but I could not find a way to open up the DTM files of Surpac in ArcGIS. I have managed to work around a bit by using Surpac to convert both files into SHP files.

But so far what I am seeing is only lines without any height data on them.

Is there a way to convert these DTM and STR data into a usable DEM files which I could run a Slope (Spatial Analysis) command?

As I only have virtually zero knowledge of Surpac and limited knowledge on ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a licence of [Surpac](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/geovia/products/surpac/) you can save your STR (string) files as AutoCAD DXF or DWG files. This will preserve the Z elevation values of the STR files allowing you to use the elevations in other software. You could try exporting the DTM surface to an XYZ file or a DXF surface from Surpac.

ArcGIS cannot open Surpac's DTM or STR file formats.

There is a free alternative software called [GEM4D](https://www.basrock.net/gem4d) that can open Surpac STR and DTM files, although I haven't gotten that particular functionality to work. The software is useful for visualizing DXF and DWG surfaces quickly as well as cutting surfaces and solids against each other.